# Caffe import Python Layer error : 'module' object has no attribute 'Layer'

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I have written a python layer to solve the data. However, it gives following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/flag/imagenet/process_test.py", line 28, in 
>       class process1(caffe.Layer): AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Layer'.

I have added the python path and built caffe `with_python_layer = 1`. Can someone help me about this?

Comment: Nobody can help with the information you've given here. If code is failing, you need at least to show that code. What is `caffe` here? How are you importing it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PYTHONPATH` variable in your `~/.bash_profile` (OSX) or `~/.bashrc` (Linux) to the caffe python.

```
export PYTHONPATH=<caffe-home>/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I add it before training but forget it before test.

Comment: Glad to know that you could fix it. Please 'mark answer as accepted' if it served the purpose or helped you to fix.